# open report created in embeddable report service

Tags: ibm-cloud, embeddable-reporting

I have successfully created a report studio report in bluemix using the embeddable reporting service.  I can display the report by going through the bluemix login process and then through the embeddable report service but I don't want users following this path - ideally I would have thought there is an url to give to display the final report.  The url I see when I run the report is https://erservice.ng.bluemix.net/viewer/viewer.jsp but if I copy/paste this into a new chrome tab I get the following error -

> Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /null/reports/phtml.

Is there an endpoint to add to the url so that users can open the report or some other url to give to report consumers?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is your Bluemix Application name. Please refer to instructions on how the ERSFit sample app is deployed (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/EmbeddableReporting/index.html#gettingstartedtemplate)